# Microsoft Face API 1.0 Error Resource Not Found

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am working on a face recognition project with Microsoft Azure Cognitive services. Not quite sure why I am not able to correct my own JSON Malformed syntax I thought I nail this 6 months ago. I want to create a group name, so I call upon  'Person Group API' and everytime I follow MS example I get errors in my code however in the API testing Console no problems here is my code example borrow from MS site :

```
 { "error": { "code": "ResourceNotFound", "message": "The requested resource was not found." } }
```

and the code which is run in Console mode :

```
static async void CreateGroup()
        {
            string key1 = "YourKey"; 
             // azure the one should work 
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

            // Request headers
           client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add
           ("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", key1);

        var uri = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/
        persongroups/{personGroupId}?" + queryString;

        HttpResponseMessage response;

        // Request body
        string groupname = "myfriends";

        string body = "{\"name\":\"" + groupname + ","+ "\"}";
        // Request body
        using (var content = new StringContent
        (body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
        {

            await client.PostAsync(uri, content)
                .ContinueWith(async responseTask =>
                {
                    var responseBody = await responseTask.Result
                    .Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                    Console.WriteLine("Response: {0}", responseBody);
                    Console.WriteLine("");

                    Console.WriteLine("Group Created.... ");
                    Console.WriteLine("Hit ENTER to exit...");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                });

            response = await client.PutAsync(uri, content);
            Console.WriteLine("what is this {0}", response.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();

        }// end of using statement 


    }// end of CreateGroup
    #endregion
```

I am guess here but I think its my JSON is malformed again and I just don't know what I am doing wrong again this time. According to the site  the field name that I require to send over to ms is `'name' : 'userData'` is optional.

Answer (score 7):

Faced the similar issue, after adding "/detect" in the uri the issue fixed. 
See the below

```
var uri = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect
```

Also make sure the subscription key is valid.

Answer (score 3):

Your request url must specify a group ID in place of where you have `{personGroupId}`.  Per the [spec](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395244) the group ID must be:

> User-provided personGroupId as a string. The valid characters include
>   numbers, English letters in lower case, '-' and '_'. The maximum
>   length of the personGroupId is 64.

Furthermore, the http verb needs to PUT, whereas you've made a `client.PostAsync` request.  So you'll need to change that to `client.PutAsync`.

Microsoft provides a client library for C# for the [Face API](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Face-Windows) where you can find working C# code.

Answer (score 1):

In python, simply this worked for me.

ENDPOINT='https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com'